# Android: Measure GPRS usage per app

Tags: android, wifi, gprs

Does anyone know if it's possible to measure the GPRS (and the WIFI) usage on a app basis?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TrafficStats`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html) to measure data usage on a per-UID basis, which roughly equates to a per-app basis. Note, though, that not all devices can report per-UID data with `TrafficStats`, and I am not completely certain why.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! Are on paternity leave... But thanks! Another question: Is it possible to count the time a device has been active and count the time the different apps have been active?